# How to create a RESTful Resource Controller in Laravel 5.2, using Artisan command (PHP)

Tags: php, laravel-5, ioc-container

I'm working with Laravel 5 and I would like to know how to generate a RESTful Resource Controller with all predefined methods using the Artisan command (PHP).

When I run `php artisan make:controller LessonsController`, it creates a controller, with no methods as shown below:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;

class LessonsController extends Controller
{


}
```

What I want to create is a complete Laravel RESTful Resource Controller with all predefined methods as in: `index(), create(), store(), show(), edit(), update()` and `destroy()`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: what version of laravel 5?

Comment: Laravel Framework version 5.2.7

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Try getting help on the command

```
php artisan help make:controller
```

If you see a `--resource` flag in the help options you are probably on **5.2 or newer** and can add that flag to the command to get a resource controller.

```
php artisan make:controller --resource SomeResourceController
```

For Laravel 5.0 and 5.1 the `make:controller` command would make a resource controller by default and the `--plain` option would make a plain controller.

[Laravel 5.2 - Restful Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers) - Default plain

[Laravel 5.1 - Restful Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers) - Default resource

[Laravel 5.0 - Restful Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#restful-resource-controllers) - Default resource

**Summary**: from Laravel 5.2 onward the `make:controller` artisan command will create a plain controller by default.

Comment: this one worked `php artisan make:controller --resource SomeResourceController`..... Thanks man

Comment: @Vicky yea because you are using 5.2.

Comment: Don' t forget to call the controller in routes/web.php as `use App\Http\Controllers\SomeResourceController;` or will raise `class not found error`

Answer (score 13):

For [Laravel 5.2](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers)

```
php artisan make:controller NameofController --resource
// It will create the controller with all methods.
```

If [Laravel < 5.2](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers)

```
php artisan make:controller NameofController
// It will create the controller with all methods.
```

and

```
php artisan make:controller NameofController --plain
// It will create the controller without any method.
```

Answer (score 3):

For default controller which have all methods you want,
`php artisan make:controller LessonsController`

If you want plain controller with no method,
`php artisan make:controller --plain LessonsController`

Comment: Dude this does not work with Laravel 5. If you do `php artisan make:controller Xyz` it will you give you a plain controller

Comment: It does not work in Laravel 5. You are working with Laravel 4 I guess.

Answer (score 2):

`php artisan make:controller "NameOfController"` - will create controller with all methods

```
php artisan make:controller "NameOfController" --plain This will create controller with no methods.
```

Best Regards, I am using laravel 5.0

Comment: vicky it does, you are just using a different version of laravel 5, which should have been noted in your question.

Comment: I know in version 4 it works fine. But it doesn't with version 5.2.7

Answer (score 2):

```
php artisan make:controller ControllerName --resource
```

Answer (score 1):

so you are using Laravel 5.2, so to have the controller with RESTful methods issue the command

```
php artisan make:controller --resource NAME_OF_CONTROLLER
```

In Laravel 5.1 and below, by default the **make:controller** command used to generate the Controller with all required methods such as 'index, create, store, show, edit, update, destroy'. And for 5.1 and below, to have the blank controller file without any methods, we used to use '--plain' parameter as

```
php artisan make:controller --plain NAME_OF_CONTROLLER
```

But with Laravel 5.2, by default the artisan command will create the bare controller file without any RESTful methods.

As Laravel 5.2 has many changes, it is better to use the 'artisan help' command as below

```
php artisan help make:controller
```

With this, we will realize the introduction of `--resource`

Please Refer the Laravel Documentation [Laravel HTTP Controllers - Artisan Command](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers)

Suggestion: As this is the change from 5.2, it would be good to edit the Post Title too.

Answer (score 0):

php artisan make:controller ItemController --resource

Answer (score 0):

```
php artisan make:controller  not_yet_existed_folder\MyController -r
```

Comment: It would help if you explained your answer.